# ActionMailer SMTP working in production but not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Seems to be the opposite problem to a lot of the questions on here. I've not been able to get the mailers working locally but then I deployed my app to Heroku and everything is fine.

No apparent errors when sending locally. Strangely though, I can have incorrect credentials locally and it will still appear to have sent ok. Almost as if it's not trying to deliver through smtp. I get a message like this in the console after sending:
`UploadMailer#complete: processed outbound mail in 32.1ms Delivered mail 63ded40c98545_b9cbb90-440@Chriss-MacBook-Pro.local.mail (1238.6ms)`

There's nothing in the SendGrid dashboard showing that it has reached their servers.

#### config/application.rb

```rb
    ...
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method :smtp
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :user_name => 'apikey',
      :password => ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],
      :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      :domain => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
      :port => 587,
      :authentication => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
```

#### Mailer and mailer view

```rb
class UploadMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def complete
    mail(to: 'me@myemail.com', subject: 'foo')
  end
end

# app/views/upload_mailer/complete.html.erb
<h2>
  Hello
</h2>
```

#### Environment

Ruby: 3.0.2 (rbenv)

Rails: 6.1.7.2

Tried on Mac and Windows(WSL)

Comment: Where do you save env variable in your local machine?

Comment: Yep, check that you've the env variables defined locally and check if the SMTP configuration defined in `application.rb` is not overridden by your `development.rb` file.

Comment: @Sharjeel `application.yml`, but the same behaviour happens when I hard-code the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was just missing

```rb
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`